# Android Media Controller Seekbar with max min volume

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have implemented a video-view with custom media controller, now I want to show a seekbar to control the volume, but that does not allow to set max and min of the seekbar. Is there any way to get max and min volume of seekbar for media-controller to set the limits of seekbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Just Simply use this code and you are all set to go.

```
   sb_Volume = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.sb_Volume);

    if(sb_Volume!=null){

          audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
          sb_Volume.setMax(audioManager
                  .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
          sb_Volume.setProgress(audioManager
                  .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


        sb_Volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);

            }
        });
    }
```